# LeakCanary ContentObserver$Transport

Tags: android, fragment, leakcanary

I'm having this leak, any guess? There are some weird references from this class. I have no contentobserver in any place of my code

```
In com.example:1.5.0:27.
 com.example.ui.record.RecordFragment has leaked:
 GC ROOT android.database.ContentObserver$Transport.mContentObserver
 references com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$SettingsObserver.this$0
 references com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.mContext
 references com.example.ui.record.RecordActivity.mFragments
 references android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.mHost
 references android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks.mFragmentManager
 references android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.mActive
 references java.util.ArrayList.array
 references array java.lang.Object[].[0]
 leaks com.example.ui.record.RecordFragment instance
 Reference Key: 15e51332-44bb-4550-864f-94023164e99c
 Device: Sony Sony Xperia SP C5303
 Android Version: 5.1.1 API: 22 LeakCanary: 1.3.1
 Durations: watch=5184ms, gc=176ms, heap dump=4015ms, analysis=25675ms
 Details:
 Instance of android.database.ContentObserver$Transport
   mContentObserver = com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$SettingsObserver [id=0x1316a8e0]
   mDescriptor = java.lang.String [id=0x7016e998]
   mObject = -1187059096
   mOwner = android.database.ContentObserver$Transport [id=0x1317f640]
 Instance of com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$SettingsObserver
   this$0 = com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow [id=0x12eb58e0]
   mHandler = android.os.Handler [id=0x1316a900]
   mLock = java.lang.Object [id=0x13142b50]
   mTransport = android.database.ContentObserver$Transport [id=0x1317f640]
 Instance of com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow
   static $staticOverhead = byte[] [id=0x70a3d751;length=104;size=120]
   static ACTION_BAR_TAG = java.lang.String [id=0x701d20a0]
   static CUSTOM_TITLE_COMPATIBLE_FEATURES = 13505
   static DEFAULT_BACKGROUND_FADE_DURATION_MS = 300
   static FLAG_RESOURCE_SET_ICON = 1
   static FLAG_RESOURCE_SET_ICON_FALLBACK = 4
   static FLAG_RESOURCE_SET_LOGO = 2
   static FOCUSED_ID_TAG = java.lang.String [id=0x701d20d0]
   static PANELS_TAG = java.lang.String [id=0x701d20b8]
   static SWEEP_OPEN_MENU = false
   static TAG = java.lang.String [id=0x701d1ab8]
   static USE_DEFAULT_TRANSITION = android.transition.TransitionSet [id=0x743b9138]
   static VIEWS_TAG = java.lang.String [id=0x701d20e8]
```

I've used LeakCanary to get this log, this is a Fragment inside an Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Have similar leak with ContentObserver. It  seems like SDK leak.

```
D/LeakCanary: * GC ROOT android.database.ContentObserver$Transport.mContentObserver
D/LeakCanary: * references com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl$5.this$0 (anonymous class
 extends android.database.ContentObserver)
D/LeakCanary: * references com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.mActivity
D/LeakCanary: * references com.luxoft.dpdcourier.ui.OnRouteActivity.defaultBarFragment
```